# Django Sql: no such function: Decimal

Tags: django

I have the following query

```
RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt=0)
```

In Django, try to debug the file /lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py to know how the sql is formed.

```
def execute_sql(self, result_type=MULTI, chunked_fetch=False, chunk_size=GET_ITERATOR_CHUNK_SIZE):
    """
    Run the query against the database and return the result(s). The
    return value is a single data item if result_type is SINGLE, or an
    iterator over the results if the result_type is MULTI.

    result_type is either MULTI (use fetchmany() to retrieve all rows),
    SINGLE (only retrieve a single row), or None. In this last case, the
    cursor is returned if any query is executed, since it's used by
    subclasses such as InsertQuery). It's possible, however, that no query
    is needed, as the filters describe an empty set. In that case, None is
    returned, to avoid any unnecessary database interaction.
    """
    result_type = result_type or NO_RESULTS
    try:
        sql, params = self.as_sql()
        if not sql:
            raise EmptyResultSet
```

At the below statement i checked the sql and params:

```
sql, params = self.as_sql()


sql = SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id", 
             "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
             "recipes_recipeposition"."quantity", 
      FROM "recipes_recipeposition" 
      WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."quantity" > %s
```

and `params = <class 'tuple'>: (Decimal('0'),)`

I tried the sql in sqlite browser:

```
SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id", 
             "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
             "recipes_recipeposition"."quantity", 
      FROM "recipes_recipeposition" 
      WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."quantity" > Decimal('0')
```

then it says no such function: Decimal

Comment: Try **`RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt=int(0))`**

Comment: I tried that and still param = Decimal('0')

Comment: try like this... "{}".format(Decimal(4))